# Where are my files / Docker Django Digital Ocean

Tags: django, docker, digital-ocean

(beginner question)

I've deployed a Docker container in a droplet on Digital Ocean, following [this tuto](https://realpython.com/blog/python/development-and-deployment-of-cookiecutter-django-via-docker/)

Everything is up and running.

But where are stored my files within my droplet?

My Dockerfile mention a /app, but there isn't any when I ssh my droplet.

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Requirements have to be pulled and installed here, otherwise caching won't work
COPY ./requirements /requirements

RUN pip install -r /requirements/production.txt \
    && groupadd -r django \
    && useradd -r -g django django

COPY . /app
RUN chown -R django /app

COPY ./compose/django/gunicorn.sh /gunicorn.sh
COPY ./compose/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh \
    && sed -i 's/\r//' /gunicorn.sh \
    && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh \
    && chown django /entrypoint.sh \
    && chmod +x /gunicorn.sh \
    && chown django /gunicorn.sh

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```